# How to look up field from last completed task in SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Is there a way to do a look up within a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow to extract a field value from the last completed task? I'm struggling to find a way do to it. Thanks.